# Do I need iptables with Azure?

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine

I'm wondering if I need to setup iptables with my Linux VM on Microsoft Azure. They do work with endpoints where I can open the ports I need to open, the others stay closed, my VM is safe for the outside but I was wondering if I still need to setup iptables for internal traffic (can another VM from Azure reach my VM?) or is my VM shielded from other VM's?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you should still protect individual VM's with normal host security, the same as you would for a traditional infrastructure, and maybe even moreso.

Azure supports [network isolation](http://azure.microsoft.com/blog/2014/03/28/network-isolation-options-for-machines-in-windows-azure-virtual-networks/), but any other VM's or services on your internal network can access your Linux VM. There's also the risk that the Azure edge firewall is compromised (unlikely, but if your VM is important enough, then your threat model should include it).

I don't think any sysadmin would advise leaving an on-premises server open, and that's when you physically control the network. I definitely would secure it when someone else is hosting things for you.

Answer (score 2):

The Linux images in the gallery do not enable the IPtables firewall inside the Linux virtual machines. So Firewalls are not enabled by default when creating a new VM (Key difference between creating a Windows VM). But IPtables firewall can be configured to provide additional filtering.

In addition , i like to share some of the key points related to Azure security.

**IDS/IPS** Microsoft GFS data centers which operates number of Microsoft cloud properties use IDS/IPS to protect Microsoft cloud assets. Have a look http://www.globalfoundationservices.com/security-and-compliance.aspx

**DDos Prevention**
Azure uses standard detection and mitigation techniques like SYN cookies and connection limits.
Microsoft Azure utilizes DHCP rate-Limiters, Host OS Packet filtering  and IP Address ACL’s. VM cannot  send DHCP responses , can send only DHCP Request.

**Hardware firewall** (Provided by Microsoft GFS – for hosting of number of Microsoft web assets)

**Host firewall**  Microsoft Azure host-level firewalls with packet filters that block cross-tenant communications via virtual networks.

**VM firewall**  Packet filters controls traffic between VMs in the same VM. VM’s cannot snoop traffic that’s not destined for them.

**Isolation** – Azure provides network isolation for each deployment with multi enforcement points.